# Firebase Realtime database shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was making a POST request for my orders to the firebase but an "ingredients" property in the orders doesn't get reflected in the firebase real-time database. Apart from this, all properties in the orders get reflected correctly. Please help.

A screenshot of my code.

```
   orderHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('This is without JSON.stringify', this.props.ingredients);
    console.log(
      'This is with JSON.stringify',
      JSON.stringify(this.props.ingredients)
    );
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const order = {
      price: this.props.price.toFixed(2),
      ingredients: this.props.ingredients,
      customer: {
        name: 'Tarun Singh',
        address: {
          street: 'TestStreet',
          zipCode: 42321,
          country: 'India',
        },
        email: 'test@test.com',
      },
      deleveryMethod: 'fastest',
    };
    console.log(
      'This is my order before making post request, ingredient property is present here',
      order
    );

    axios
      .post('/orders.json', order)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  };
```

My console output, also gives the componentWillMount warning I used once but after that I removed it, still, the warning remains.
[image]

However, when I make the POST request, the "ingredients" property doesn't get reflected at the firebase.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: okay, I have posted the actual code.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you also change `console.log(this.props.ingredients);` to ` console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.ingredients));` and include the updated code and its output? I wanna make sure it's exactly what you show in your screenshot, as Chrome can do some trickery in its console logging otherwise.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have made the necessary changes, please look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this code:

```
console.log(
  'This is with JSON.stringify',
  JSON.stringify(this.props.ingredients)
);
```

Outputs this:

> This is with JSON.stringify, []

So it seems that by the time this code runs, your `this.props.ingredients` hasn't been populated yet.

When a path is empty/has no value, Firebase doesn't store it. So that explains why the `ingredients` property from your app doesn't show up in the JSON of the database.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, can you help me with the compoenentWillMount function I think that's the reason why ingredients don't populate. Here's my file [Please look into this](https://pastebin.com/YBvzpMxN). What can be an alternate way to obtain the same functionality as componentWillMount as React no longer supports it.